# Gradient Not showing swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, cgcolor

I am fairly new to `Swift` and `XCode`. I have just learnt how to create a gradient on a Navigation Controller from a tutorial video, however in the video I watch the guy used a `UIColor` and I want to use a `CGColor`, so I used this code:

```
class func gradientLayerForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CAGradientLayer {
  let layer = CAGradientLayer()
  let topColor = UIColor(red: 244, green: 45, blue: 78, alpha: 100)
  let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 245, green: 67, blue: 58, alpha: 100)

  layer.bounds = bounds
  layer.colors = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]

  return layer
}
```

However when I build and run the project, nothing appears, I get no error or warning the Debug box. Hope someone can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using custom colors you need to divide the color by 255 e.g. `UIColor(red: 244/255, green: 45/255, blue: 78/255, alpha: 100)`.

It appears you haven't done that, so I would recommend trying:

```
let topColor = UIColor(red: 244/255, green: 45/255, blue: 78/255, alpha: 100)
let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 67/255, blue: 58/255, alpha: 100)
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: I've just tried it and not it works! Thanks ever so much for your help. Much appreciated

Comment: @TimSmith So it works? I think you mean 'now' instead of 'not'. No problem, happy to help. I just recommend searching the internet before coming to SO.

Comment: Also @TimSmith Could you accept the answer if it works (-:

Comment: Yes I will accept the answer as it has solved my problem